# Ethernet auto-sensing and auto-negotiation error?

Tags: networking, home-networking, switch

In a network where Franck has only one RJ45 port accessible (see Network topology, situation 1), I add a switch to get an additionnal RJ45 port, everything is fine (situation 2), but when I remove the switch and get back to situation 1, Franck's desktop computer is not getting Internet completly back. (ping on 8.8.8.8 responds ounce every 4 requests and we can load 1 web page if we are very lucky)

Note about the modem: we can only reboot the modem and don't know anything about its configuration.

Situation 1:

- Everyone has Internet

Situation 2:

- a switch is added in Franck's flat
- everything works directly as expeted

Situation 3 (back to situation 1)

- the switch is removed
- If Franck's laptop is pluged-in, it gets Internet normaly
- If Franck's desktop is pluged-in, it gets unusable Internet (1 ping out of 3)
- If modem is rebooted, everything works as expected (we are back to 1)

The problem seams to be with Franck desktop's NIC, as his laptop never gets a bad Internet connexion.

Might this be an unpropper duplex mode detection ? Maybe a cable (crossover/straight) problem ?

I will investigate those possibilities now, but if I'm wrong maybe you can help me diagnose why I have to reboot the modem when we remove the switch.

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kOaA.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Manually setting speed and duplex when auto-negotiation is in question is a good start to troubleshooting...
As cable lengths and EMF environments move towards specification limits, the quality(correct crimping sequence), and condition of the cable become greater factors in its performance.

Comment: Setting speed and duplex manually didn't solved issues we encountered.
But changing the cable seamed to do the trick xP.

Because I'm not at Franck's flat often, I cannot diagnose often.

Thank you.

Comment: Was the cable home-made...?

Comment: No it was not. Sorry for the late answer.